# Cosmos on Wirecloud

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

Taking as a reference public documentation (https://wirecloud.conwet.etsiinf.upm.es/slides/1.2_Integration%20with%20other%20GEs.html#slide16) I wonder if at this point there is any progress on connecting Wirecloud & Cosmos in order to retrieve historical data and visualised it over mashups setups.

If not, could you give any direction so I can give a try implementing something around this?

Note: I have already checked some of the available documentation, and it looks to me that my desired feature could be tackled by a simple python implementation to retrieve HDFS files to the appropriated NGSI format, Is it right?

Nevertheless, I believe it will be a dirty mechanism. What should be the recommended way?

Comment: On Fiwares awards in 2014, I developed an hive client to connect orion using Thrift: https://github.com/LeonanCarvalho/PHP-HiveClient
I'm not sure if cosmos still support it, but using your own API you can build a widget to consume an API to send your data from cosmos as a row data (json or something else). This method don't require any access on files, but need to be evaluated.

Comment: thanks @LeoanCarvalho. I will take a look

Comment: where I said "orion using Thrift" I would like mean "cosmos using thrift"

Comment: got it. Although to be honest, so far I still struggling with the hive setup, I cannot find any documentation or guide to appropriately set it up on my cosmos instance, Do you have any hint to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly hope not to be cheating by answering my own questions and marking them as correct, but I would like to leave a record of a solution for those folks that might be experiencing same troubles as me.

I have developed a quick and dirty mechanism to retrieve HDFS files into NGSI formats so we can retrieve historical data like we do with Orion widgets.

https://github.com/netzahdzc/cloudCos

Please note, that this is a quite working progress, so there are some hardcode that I hope eventually fix.

Answer (score 0):

Official Cosmos-WireCloud integration is currently not available, although there are third-party widgets using cosmos out there.

In my opinion, the best option for accessing the HDFS filesystem, is using [WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html) (you will need adding a FIWARE token into the request for authentication).

It should also be possible to connect to Hive (see this [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/29) for more info)

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go straight with the option to extract data using Hive, since looks more flexible for future needs. I have created a mother question about how to handle Hive by Cygnus: Do you have any idea how to handle such thing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177655/enabling-hive-on-cygnus).