# Enabling Hive on Cygnus

Tags: fiware-cygnus

So far, my Orion subscriptions are appropriately creating hfds files on Cosmos instance. However, since (my project's requirements) I will be dealing with Wirecloud, to do so, seems that a good approach is to perform Hive queries to retrieve historical data.

Thus, How can I settle my Cygnus config files to automatically create tables and populate Hive?

Will using below configuration be enough?:

```
# Hive enabling
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive = true
# Hive server version, 1 or 2 (ignored if hive is false)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.server_version = 2
# Hive FQDN/IP address of the Hive server (ignored if hive is false)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.host = x.y.z.w
# Hive port for Hive external table provisioning (ignored if hive is false)
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.port = 10000
```

Is this documentation up to date (i.e., http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.0/cygnus-ngsi/installation_and_administration_guide/ngsi_agent_conf/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only missing:

```
cygnusagent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hive.db_type = default-db | namespace-db
```

The above command will allow you switching form the default Hive database, or a private database of your own.

Additionally, if using FIWARE Lab global instance of Cosmos, the `hdfs_password` must be equals to your OAuth2 token.

Comment: sorry for this question but: Does it mean that the Cosmo instance (on FIWARE) does not include hive service? os if the default option you mentioned the service already provided for Cosmos? if my last hypo is true, how can I have access to the hive on my Cosmos ? any doc link? thanks in advance @frb

Comment: Yes, global instance of Cosmos exposes a HiveServer2 endpoint. This endpoint is reachable as any HiveServer2 endpoint through JDBC or Thrift-based protocol. You will have to create your own client, examples can be found [here (Java)](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/tree/master/resources/java/hiveserver2-client) and [here (Python)](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/resources/python/hiveserver2-client.py).

Comment: Regarding the `db_type` paremeter and its possible values, `default-db` means your Hive tables will be created under the general default database, while `namespace-db` means the Hive tables will be created under a privte database of your own.

Comment: ok great. Just to make it clear. If I want to use the recommended client script taking into account the Cosmos instance on Fiware: How do I have access to hive credentials? should I use cosmos IP and port instead of <hive_host>  <hive_port>? How can I know what <db_name> has been created? Should I use my Cosmos username and OAuth2 token for <hadoop_user> <hadoop_password>?

Comment: Regarding Cygnus automatic creation of Hive tables within Cosmos Global Instance, you have to specify the single host for all Cosmos computing services. i.e. `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org`, and TCP port `10000`. In addition, you must decide if you want your tables within the default database, or wihtin a database of your own called as your Cosmos username. Finally, you have to provide your OAuth2 token as Cosmos password (the name is not the best, it refers to a previous Cosmos deployment where Hive was protected with password instead of an OAuth2 token).

Comment: Regarding another client of your own different to Cygnus (i.e. some client in charge of reading data from Hive tables, or making queries), the same applies. Host: `computing.cosmos.lab.fiware.org`. Port: 10000. Password when establishing the connection: your OAuth2 token.